# How to perform a $\chi^2$ test when the expected value is zero

Tags: probability, distributions, chi-squared-test

I have performed an experiment and obtained the following data:
[image: Sample experiment]

The black dots are the recorded values at a given time and the red line is a curve of best fit. Now I want to perform a chi-squared test with the fit, but the only problem is that the fit is zero at some points. Since chi-squared is defined as:
$$\chi^2=\sum \frac{(obs-exp)^2}{exp}$$
I will eventually divide by zero. Clearly this cant happen. I have thought about just shifting both my data and model up by 5 as that would get rid of any cases where I would have to divide by 5. But doesn't that as chi-square becomes:
$$\chi^2=\sum \frac{((obs+5)-(exp+5))^2}{exp+5}=\sum \frac{(obs-exp)^2}{exp+5}$$
So all adding 5 does is deflate my value. What is the proper way to handle this?

Comment: You appear to have a non-standard interpretation of "obs" and "exp" in this test.  This definition of the statistic supposes "obs" is a *count.*  In what sense are your Intensity values counts??

Comment: The y-axis seems a continuous variable. Chi square test is used to analyze proportions, or association between categorical variables. Are you sure chi square is the method to be applied here?